# Changing default order of posts in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a blog like rails app with posts. the posts can be order by most popular or newest. The most popular is the default order and the homepage, Id like to change this to be the newest order instead. Since Im still pretty new to rails I hired a programmer to do most of the work, However I know this is a pretty simple fix, I just don't know what to change. I think its something I need to change in either the post_controller or the post model, but If you nee to see something else let me know and ill put it up.

post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 include UrlHelp

   def self.highest_voted
  self.order(:cached_votes_down)
 end
end
```

post_controller.rb

```
 def index
 @posts = grab_correct_post
 end

def grab_correct_post
  if params[:sort_by] == "added_on"
  @added_on = "sort-active"
  Post.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page],  per_page: 7)
else
  @most_popular = "sort-active"
  Post.all.order(:cached_votes_score =>:desc).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 7)
   end
```

Comment: Did you consider using [`reorder`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/reorder)?

Comment: @spickermann what do I change though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the selector for swapping the sort order and get the sort_by value sent for most popular then you can change grab_correct_post to the following to change the default

```
def grab_correct_post
  if params[:sort_by] == "<sort_by_value_for popular>"
    @most_popular = "sort-active"
    Post.all.order(:cached_votes_score =>:desc).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 7)
  else
    @added_on = "sort-active"
    Post.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page],  per_page: 7)
  end
end
```

Comment: Yep this worked! I knew its was something super simple. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you could reverse the order of the if-else blocks in the `grab_correct_post` method:

```
def grab_correct_post
  if params[:sort_by] == "most_popular"
    @most_popular = "sort-active"
    Post.all.order(:cached_votes_score =>:desc).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 7)
  else
    @added_on = "sort-active"
    Post.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page],  per_page: 7)
  end
end
```

Note that I simply took a guess as to what the `:sort_by` parameter value should be for sorting by popularity, so be sure to change from `"most_popular"` to whatever you actually use.